# socket server broadcasting to clients, but not receiving from both

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I'm really confused by this error I've bumped into and am hoping someone can tell me why my code is responding oddly.

I have made a simple game that should allow clients to press button A and send a message 'A' to the server, which will then add 1 to the A variable, and send the number value of A (compiled server side) back to all the clients. I was hoping that if there were 3 users, and each pressed A, then the server would calculate A=3.

Here is my code:

```
var io = require("socket.io").listen(8888);
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
console.log("Server has started.");




io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {

var A = 0;
var B = 0;

    socket.on("message", function (data) {

        if (data == 'A') {
            A++;
            console.log(A);
        }
        else if (data == 'B') {
            B++;
            console.log(B);
        }
    var M = [A + '' + B]
        function M(A, B) {
        this.first = A;
        this.second = B;
        }
        this.all = function() {
            return A + '' + B;
        }
            console.log(M); 
            socket.emit("message", M);
            socket.broadcast.emit("message", M);
    });



});
```

The result is each player seems to be in their own tally, so that each player has to press A 3 times for A to = 3, but all players receive the broadcast of each others button presses. Could someone please tell me why the clients are receiving, but the server is accepting 'A' in 3 separate stacks from the clients?

Comment: What server language is this?  It looks like Javascript, what is the server runtime?

Comment: oh it's javascript, prob should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Not sure about the server runtime, how would I check that out?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that each client makes its own connection to the server. Any variables you have within the on-connection function will only be for that one client.

You can move the declarations of `A` and `B` to the toplevel, so all the connections will be accessing the same variables.